# How to integrate Gradle jmeter plugin with jmeter + jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jmeter

1. How to locate build.gradle file ?. Under which folder i need to create build.gradle file ? I am saving all my .jmx test files under jmeter/bin folder
2. Do i need to create a new java project in IDE to use Gradle?

Please provide detail steps to integrate Gradle jmeter plugin with jmeter + Jenkins

[image: Gradle project]

Comment: Which plugin are you using? I would recommend using this: http://jmeter.foragerr.net/ I am the author, and I'd be happy to help you out with usage and issues.

Comment: Sounds to me like you do not have a java source project already? You're creating a project just to use jmeter?

Comment: Yes i dont have any java project. I am just running my .jmx files using shell command in Jenkins job. Can you please share sample java source project with gradle ?

Comment: I posted an answer below, does that not help?

Comment: @Rage-  I have created a new java project. Created folder structure as below and added .jmx file. Created build.gradle with below content. How plugin will know which test plan(s) to execute and which jmeter file i need to change/add here ?

Comment: by default, the plugin will execute all jmx test plans in /src/test/jmeter sequentially when you execute `gradle jmrun`. You only need to do custom config if you want to run a specific test, or you place the tests in a different folder.

Comment: Sorry for asking more questions. Under which folder level i need to execute 'gradle jmrun'. Getting 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command, Refer main question for my project

Comment: i am using foragerr plugin for integrating jmeter with gradle. But i didn't found much documentation for customizing this.@RaGe can you help me to understand how to customize log4j2 location and how to pass parameters to jmx file etc..?

Answer (score 1):

To create a standalone gradle project that runs jmeter tests, you can create a new folder and add a file build.gradle to it, with the following contents:

```
plugins {
  id "net.foragerr.jmeter" version "1.0.3-2.13"
}
```

Create a folder `src/test/jmeter` and place all your test `.jmx` files there.

From jenkins you can run `gradle jmrun` to run tests and `gradle jmreport` to generate reports.

Comment: It would be helpful if share sample skeleton java project with Grandle

Comment: There is a sample project here: https://github.com/jmeter-gradle-plugin/jmeter-gradle-plugin-simple-example . clone the project and run ./gradlew jmrun to execute the test bundled with the sample project.

Comment: This Plugin has Support till Apache JMeter 4.0 only. For JMeter 5.0+ use 
[link](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.quintessent.jmeter)