# Can I add Jmeter to the project that use Gradle Java and Junit 5?

Tags: java, gradle, jmeter, performance-testing

I have an Automation test project with an API test included.
I use for that JUnit, Retrofit2, Java, and Gradle. 
I want to integrate Jmeter to those tests and run performance testing using those tests. It is possible?
Can I (for example) package all of those tests to the jar, and run it using plugin before running the tests? 
I saw some topics on the stack overflow and other forums, but it was for Maven and Junit.

Comment: Check this maven plugin, I might help you https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin

Comment: This could be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35595537/how-to-integrate-gradle-jmeter-plugin-with-jmeter-jenkins

Comment: Thank you guys I will check those.